Маркированные списки через Python-docx-template (docxtpl)
Такой вопрос. По работе понадобилось генерировать отчеты из шаблона ворда, использовать эту библиотеку. В части отчета нужно сгенерировать подобный маркированный список:

первыйэлемент
второйэлемент
третийэлемент

Причем тег должен быть под вторым номером.
в шаблоне это выглядит примерно так:

первыйэлемент
{{ item }}
третийэлемент

Но в таком варианте несколько минусов:

если нет данных для элемента, он оставляет пустую строку и получается такой вид:


первыйэлемент

третийэлемент

А должно быть два маркированных элемента такого вида:

первыйэлемент
третийэлемент


если тег вставить в конец предыдущего тега, при вставке элемента оно сломает табуляцию.

Как решить эту проблему?

Если скрыть/показать конкретно один пункт по какому-то условию, то его можно обернуть в тег {% if %}, как в обычном jinja2: https://docs-python.ru/packages/modul-jinja2-python/operator-if-elif-else-shablonah-jinja2/ (там примеры для html, но суть должна быть примерно такой же). Если в принципе все пункты могут меняться, то имеет смысл оставить только один пункт списка, и его обернуть в тег {% for %}

пустые строки в таком варианте все равно добавляет если данных нет:(

Оформил ответом

docxtpl работает на основе шаблонизатора jinja2. В jinja2 есть управляющие конструкции типа if или for, работающие примерно аналогично таким же конструкциям в python (только блоки кода обозначаются не отступами, а закрывающими тегами endif и endfor).
Например, скрытие/отображение элемента с помощью if (если в item будет None, то его строка вообще не отобразится):
{%- if item %}
- {{ item }}
{%- endif %}

- черточка после % означает, что сама эта строка с тегом будет удалена
Отображение набора элементов с помощью for:
{%- for item in items %}
- {{ item }}
{%- endfor %}

В коде через items передается список элементов, при заполнении шаблона одна строка - {{ item }} превратится в несколько строк по количеству элементов в списке items. Если список items будет пустой, то вообще ни одна строка не отобразится.
Рабочий пример кода:
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate

doc = DocxTemplate('template.docx')

item = None  # Пустой элемент, соответствующий пункт не отобразится

items = [
    "первый элемент",
    "второй элемент",
    "третий элемент",
]

context = {'item': item, 'items': items}

doc.render(context)
doc.save('output.docx')

Шаблон (файл template.docx):

Или такой вариант, сами строки с if/endif тоже могут быть элементами списка (при заполнении шаблона удалятся, благодаря "магической" черточке):

Результат заполнения шаблона (файл output.docx):


Спасибо огромное!
